# My application is working in an endless loop

Tags: java, android, loops, localization

So I have an application which has to monitor and range after beacons and than calculates the position of the user. After calculating this , the value is passed to the Wayfindigoverlayactivity.class where the value should be putt on the map with the blue dot.
I don know how to assign the value to the blue dot but before that my application is working on an endless loop and is opening the activity on ranging about 100x .

RangingActivity:

```
package com.indooratlas.android.sdk.examples.wayfinding;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Context;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocationRequest;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.examples.R;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class RangingActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer,Runnable{

    protected static final String TAG = "RangingActivity";
    public LatLng center;
    private final BlockingQueue queue;
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ranging);
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        beaconManager.bind(this);

    }



    @Override

    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override

    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override

    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {


        RangeNotifier rangeNotifier = new RangeNotifier() {

            @Override

            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

                int beacon_number = beacons.size();

                Beacon[] beacon_array = beacons.toArray(new Beacon[beacons.size()]);
                Beacon device1 = null, device2 = null, device3 = null;

                Constants constants = new Constants();

                float txPow1 = 0;
                double RSSI1Unfiltered = 0;
                double RSSI2Unfiltered = 0;
                float txPow2 = 0;
                double RSSI3Unfiltered = 0;
                float txPow3 = 0;
                if (beacon_number == 4) {

                    if (beacon_array[0].getIdentifier(0).toString() == constants.DEVICE1_UUID) {
                        device1 = beacon_array[0];
                    } else if (beacon_array[1].getIdentifier(0).toString() == constants.DEVICE1_UUID) {
                        device1 = beacon_array[1];
                    } else {
                        device1 = beacon_array[2];
                    }

                    if (beacon_array[0].getIdentifier(0).toString() == constants.DEVICE2_UUID) {
                        device2 = beacon_array[0];
                    } else if (beacon_array[1].getIdentifier(0).toString() == constants.DEVICE2_UUID) {
                        device2 = beacon_array[1];
                    } else {
                        device2 = beacon_array[2];
                    }

                    if (beacon_array[0].getIdentifier(0).toString() == constants.DEVICE3_UUID) {
                        device3 = beacon_array[0];
                    } else if (beacon_array[1].getIdentifier(0).toString() == constants.DEVICE3_UUID) {
                        device3 = beacon_array[1];
                    } else {
                        device3 = beacon_array[2];
                    }
                    RSSI1Unfiltered = device1.getRssi();
                    RSSI2Unfiltered = device2.getRssi();
                    RSSI3Unfiltered = device3.getRssi();

                    txPow1 = device1.getTxPower();
                    txPow2 = device2.getTxPower();
                    txPow3 = device3.getTxPower();


                } else if (beacon_number > 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "didRangeBeaconsInRegion called with beacon count:  " + beacons.size());
                    for (int i = 0; i < beacon_number; i++) {
                        Beacon nextBeacon = beacon_array[i];
                        Log.d(TAG, "The next beacon " + nextBeacon.getIdentifier(0) + " is about " + nextBeacon.getDistance() + " meters away." + "RSSI is: " + nextBeacon.getRssi());
                        logToDisplay("The next beacon" + nextBeacon.getIdentifier(0) + " is about " + nextBeacon.getDistance() + " meters away." + "RSSI is: " + nextBeacon.getRssi());
                    }
                }
                    Log.d(TAG, "FLOAT!!!!!!!!" + txPow1);
                    LocationFinder locationFinder = new LocationFinder();
                    //pass location
                     center = locationFinder.findLocation(RSSI1Unfiltered, txPow1, RSSI2Unfiltered, txPow2, RSSI3Unfiltered, txPow3);
                     Log.d(TAG, "Current coordinates: asta e asta e !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! " + center.toString());
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putParcelable("b", center);

                    Intent intent00 = new Intent(RangingActivity.this, WayfindingOverlayActivity.class);
                    intent00.putExtras(args);
                    startActivity(intent00);



            }

            private void logToDisplay(final String s) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        EditText editText = RangingActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                        editText.append(s+"\n");
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        try {

            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));

            beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier);

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        }

    }



/* Blockinqueue try---not working

       RangingActivity(BlockingQueue q)
       {
           queue = q;
       }


        public void run() {

            LatLng res;
            try
            {
                res = center;
                queue.put(res);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

*/

}
```

Everything works fine here , until I open the next class where my map is the WayfindingOverlayActivity

```
package com.indooratlas.android.sdk.examples.wayfinding;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.GroundOverlay;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.GroundOverlayOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocation;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocationListener;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocationManager;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocationRequest;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IAOrientationListener;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IAOrientationRequest;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IAPOI;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IARegion;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IARoute;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IAWayfindingListener;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IAWayfindingRequest;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.examples.R;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.examples.SdkExample;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.resources.IAFloorPlan;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.resources.IALatLng;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.resources.IALocationListenerSupport;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.resources.IAVenue;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

@SdkExample(description = R.string.example_wayfinding_description)
public class WayfindingOverlayActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback ,Runnable{

    private final BlockingQueue queue;
    private static final String TAG = "IndoorAtlasExample";

    /* used to decide when bitmap should be downscaled */
    private static final int MAX_DIMENSION = 2048;

    //kalman filter

    private static final double KALMAN_R = 0.125d;
    private static final double KALMAN_Q = 0.5d;


    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    private Circle mCircle;
    private IARegion mOverlayFloorPlan = null;
    private GroundOverlay mGroundOverlay = null;
    private IALocationManager mIALocationManager;
    private Target mLoadTarget;
    private boolean mCameraPositionNeedsUpdating = true; // update on first location
    private Marker mDestinationMarker;
    private Marker mHeadingMarker;
    private IAVenue mVenue;
    private List<Marker> mPoIMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Polyline> mPolylines = new ArrayList<>();
    private IARoute mCurrentRoute;

    private IAWayfindingRequest mWayfindingDestination;
    private IAWayfindingListener mWayfindingListener = new IAWayfindingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onWayfindingUpdate(IARoute route) {
            mCurrentRoute = route;
            if (hasArrivedToDestination(route)) {
                // stop wayfinding
                showInfo("You're there!");
                mCurrentRoute = null;
                mWayfindingDestination = null;
                mIALocationManager.removeWayfindingUpdates();
            }
            updateRouteVisualization();
        }
    };

    private IAOrientationListener mOrientationListener = new IAOrientationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHeadingChanged(long timestamp, double heading) {
            updateHeading(heading);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChange(long timestamp, double[] quaternion) {
            // we do not need full device orientation in this example, just the heading
        }
    };

    private int mFloor;

    // circle
    private void showLocationCircle(LatLng center, double accuracyRadius) {

        if (mCircle == null) {
            // location can received before map is initialized, ignoring those updates
            if (mMap != null) {
                mCircle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                        .center(center)
                        .radius(accuracyRadius)
                        .fillColor(0x201681FB)
                        .strokeColor(0x500A78DD)
                        .zIndex(1.0f)
                        .visible(true)
                        .strokeWidth(5.0f));
                mHeadingMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(center)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_blue_dot))
                        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                        .flat(true));
            }
        } else {
            // move existing markers position to received location
            mCircle.setCenter(center);
            mHeadingMarker.setPosition(center);
            mCircle.setRadius(accuracyRadius);
        }
    }

    private void updateHeading(double heading) {
        if (mHeadingMarker != null) {
            mHeadingMarker.setRotation((float) heading);
        }
    }

    private IALocationListener mListener = new IALocationListenerSupport() {

        public void onLocationChanged(IALocation location) {
            Log.d(TAG, "NEW" + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
            if (mMap == null) {
                return;
            }

            final LatLng center = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
            final int newFloor = location.getFloorLevel();
            if (mFloor != newFloor) {
                updateRouteVisualization();
            }
            mFloor = newFloor;

            showLocationCircle(center, location.getAccuracy());

            if (mCameraPositionNeedsUpdating) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(center, 15.5f));
                mCameraPositionNeedsUpdating = false;
            }
        }

    };

    /**
     * Listener that changes overlay if needed
     */
    private IARegion.Listener mRegionListener = new IARegion.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onEnterRegion(final IARegion region) {
            if (region.getType() == IARegion.TYPE_FLOOR_PLAN) {
                Log.d(TAG, "enter floor plan " + region.getId());
                mCameraPositionNeedsUpdating = true; // entering new fp, need to move camera
                if (mGroundOverlay != null) {
                    mGroundOverlay.remove();
                    mGroundOverlay = null;
                }
                mOverlayFloorPlan = region; // overlay will be this (unless error in loading)
                fetchFloorPlanBitmap(region.getFloorPlan());
                //setupPoIs(mVenue.getPOIs(), region.getFloorPlan().getFloorLevel());
            } else if (region.getType() == IARegion.TYPE_VENUE) {
                mVenue = region.getVenue();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onExitRegion(IARegion region) {
        }

    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // prevent the screen going to sleep while app is on foreground
        findViewById(android.R.id.content).setKeepScreenOn(true);

        // instantiate IALocationManager
        mIALocationManager = IALocationManager.create(this);


        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMapAsync(this);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, RangingActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(myIntent);

        Intent intent00 = getIntent();
        LatLng center = intent00.getParcelableExtra("b");
        Log.d(TAG,"Location!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + center);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // remember to clean up after ourselves
        mIALocationManager.destroy();
    }
    /*Some blockingqueue---does not work
    public class BlockinQueueExample
    {
        public void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            BlockingQueue q = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1000);
            RangingActivity producer = new RangingActivity(q);
            WayfindingOverlayActivity consumer = new WayfindingOverlayActivity(q);

            new Thread(producer).start();
            new Thread(consumer).start();

        }
    }

    WayfindingOverlayActivity(BlockingQueue q)
    {
        this.queue = q;
    }
    public void run() {
       try{
           queue.take();
           Log.d(TAG,"BIANCABICA"+queue.take());
          }
       catch (InterruptedException e)
           {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }

       }

*/
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // start receiving location updates & monitor region changes
        mIALocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(IALocationRequest.create(), mListener);
        mIALocationManager.registerRegionListener(mRegionListener);
        mIALocationManager.registerOrientationListener(
                // update if heading changes by 1 degrees or more
                new IAOrientationRequest(1, 0),
                mOrientationListener);

        if (mWayfindingDestination != null) {
            mIALocationManager.requestWayfindingUpdates(mWayfindingDestination, mWayfindingListener);
        }
    }
```

EDIT , LAUNCHER ACTIVITY

```
package com.indooratlas.android.sdk.examples;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.examples.imageview.ImageViewActivity;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.examples.wayfinding.MonitoringActivity;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.examples.wayfinding.RangingActivity;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.examples.wayfinding.WayfindingOverlayActivity;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.RegionBootstrap;

public class Bianca extends Activity implements BootstrapNotifier {
    private static final String TAG = "RANGE";
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private Button button;
    private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;

    private boolean haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = false;

    private MonitoringActivity monitoringActivity = null;

    private String cumulativeLog = "";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);
        BeaconManager beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
   //--------------------------------meniu -------------------------------
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openAct();
            }
        });

        Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openAct2();
            }
        });

        Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openAct3();
            }
        });

        Button button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openAct4();
            }
        });
    //-----------------------------meniu----------------------------------
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,WayfindingOverlayActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("My Notification Channel ID",
                    "My Notification Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription("My Notification Channel Description");
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                    Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            builder.setChannelId(channel.getId());
        }

        beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(builder.build(), 456);
        Log.d(TAG, "setting up background monitoring for beacons and power saving");
        // wake up the app when a beacon is seen
        Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion",
                null, null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap((BootstrapNotifier) this, region);
        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
    }

    public void openAct()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WayfindingOverlayActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openAct2()
    {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, RangingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
    }
    public void openAct3()
    {
        Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, ImageViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent4);
    }

    public void openAct4()
    {
        Intent intent5 = new Intent(this,RegionsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent5);
    }
    public void disableMonitoring() {

        if (regionBootstrap != null) {

            regionBootstrap.disable();

            regionBootstrap = null;

        }

    }


    public void enableMonitoring() {

        Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion",

                null, null, null);

        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap((BootstrapNotifier) this, region);

    }

    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {

        // In this example, this class sends a notification to the user whenever a Beacon

        // matching a Region (defined above) are first seen.

        Log.d(TAG, "did enter region.");

        if (!haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot) {

            Log.d(TAG, "auto launching MainActivity");


            // The very first time since boot that we detect an beacon, we launch the

            // MainActivity

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, WayfindingOverlayActivity.class);

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Important:  make sure to add android:launchMode="singleInstance" in the manifest

            // to keep multiple copies of this activity from getting created if the user has

            // already manually launched the app.

            this.startActivity(intent);

            haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = true;

        } else {

            if (monitoringActivity != null) {

                // If the Monitoring Activity is visible, we log info about the beacons we have

                // seen on its display

                Log.d(TAG, "I see a beacon again");

            } else {

                // If we have already seen beacons before, but the monitoring activity is not in

                // the foreground, we send a notification to the user on subsequent detections.

                Log.d(TAG, "Sending notification.");


            }

        }
    }


        public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {

           Log.d(TAG,"I no longer see a beacon.");

        }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {

    }


}
```

The second class is not fully posted , only where I make changes.
The intent in the second class is in the OnCreate part
The location is calculated in the logcat , the only problem is that the application is working in a loop
Please help me , I am stuck. Thanks

Comment: intent in the second class is causing the loop as u placed it in the `onCreate()`. Why is it there for?

Comment: if I delete that the ranging is not showing up on the device.Can u say how to assign that localation value to the blue dot?

Comment: Which is the launcher `Activity` out of two ?

Comment: There is a another launcher activity I post it now , and from there I launch the map activity which is the Wayfindingoverlayactivity.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you only need to open `RangingActivity` from `onCreate()` of `WayFindingOverlayActivity` if `center` is null. This means, we need to open `RangingActivity` to get the value for `center`. Doing null check for the `center` will also ensure that the application doesn't go in loop and proceed when we have the value for `center`.  The code in the `onCreate()` of `WayFindingOverlayActivity` may look like this :

```
    // edited here
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, RangingActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(myIntent);
    } else{
         LatLng center = extras.getParcelable("b");
         Log.d("Location!!", center);
         // call showLocationCircle() to show the blue dot
         showLocationCircle(center, yourAccuracyRadius);
    }
```

Comment: It is still working in a loop , but other activity is in loop. Do you have time to share your email address to help me please? Thank you

Comment: which activity is in loop now? With u providing info here, if not me, other people will also be able to help you.

Comment: Now the WayfindingOverlayActivity is in loop. The one with the map where I put the code from the onCreate() which you provided

Comment: The app is crashing because it says that : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference    :(

Comment: does the edited answer fix the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Yes , thank you! But sadly the application is still not working correctly. It has a loop or something like this . The activity with the map , I can not close it . And if I open the another activity the RangingActivity it is working in a loop.